# How to reduce streams with Double datatype

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have an `ArrayList` of user-defined object employee as

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    Double age;
    Double salary
}
```

I am trying to reduce the above list as a stream via the following code

```
Double totalSalary = empList.stream().parallel().filter(x-> x.getname().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ")).reduce(0,(subTotal, sal)-> subTotal + dp.getSalary(), DoubleExpression::add);
```

This does not compile and gives an error. How can I achieve my desired objective?

Comment: Please include the error message in your question by [edit]ing it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to `map` the Employee object into a double salary. Then only you can do the reduction step. Moreover, the reduction step takes an identity element and a binary operator. But you have passed three arguments there, which is flawed too.

```
double totalSalary = empList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
    .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
    .sum();
```

Here's the equivalent reduction. Notice that 0 is the identity element for this reduction.

```
double totalSalary = empList.stream()
    .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
    .mapToDouble(Employee::getSalary)
    .reduce(0, Double::sum);
```

Comment: `Double.NaN` as an identity for `sum` would work with `map` as well, such as `.map(Employee::getSalary).reduce(Double.NaN, Double::sum);`. On another note: There is a three-argument API for reduction as well `reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U, ? super T, U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)` in this case same as `.reduce(Double.NaN, Double::sum, Double::sum)`

Comment: But, the identity element for sum should be 0, Not `Double.NaN`. Anyway thanks for pointing out the 3 argument overload of the reduce, which I have never used so far.

Comment: The three-argument overload is though present with `Stream` and not the primitive special variants. The reason for using `NaN` is also something that I added to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58356211/1746118).

Answer (score 2):

[Ravindra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355224/1746118) provides a correct solution, but to understand in detail why your solution doesn't work, consider these:

```
Double totalSalary = empList.stream().parallel()
        .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
        // crucial aspect of mapping to the type that you want to reduce
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        // reduction as a stage of stream pipeline execution
        .reduce(0,  // identity element for sum, but with a flaw!!
                (subTotal, sal) -> Double.sum(subTotal, sal), // accumulator to sum double values
                Double::sum // the combiner function compatible with accumulation
               );
```

The reason why the identity is flawed is that, because of 0, the type of `subTotal` in the accumulator would not be inferred as `double` as expected by the `Double#sum` method. Hence updating the code further to using `Double.NaN` would make it work as :

```
Double totalSalary = empList.stream().parallel()
        .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        .reduce(Double.NaN, Double::sum, Double::sum); // identity element and method reference for accumulator
```

Though note, this could be simply represented with the exclusion of the combiner in this case as:

```
Double totalSalary = empList.stream().parallel()
        .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("XYZ"))
        .map(Employee::getSalary)
        .reduce(Double.NaN, Double::sum);
```

and since `sum` eventually is an operation of *primitive types*, it would be much convenient to use the `DoubleStream` mapping which is a primitive specialization of the stream for double-valued elements.

Comment: Thanks Naman for the detailed description... really helpful. Thumbs up man!!